# jQuery toggleClass and check checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I can't seem to get this to work. If I remove the checkbox portion of the script the toggle class works but if I add it, then it no longer toggle's the class. I'm a total amateur at this so I would greatly appreciate any help. I'm using jQuery version 1.4.1. Thanks.

```
$("li.imprint").click(function() {
  $(this,"li.imprint").toggleClass('selected').children("input[@type=checkbox]")[0].click();
});
```

So essentially I'm building a web form for people to customize pens. So they need to choose what color imprint they want. Rather than just a boring list of colors, I wanted to show a swatch of the color. So I figured I would create a list, put some checkboxes so they can select the colors and use CSS to hide the actual checkbox so it's all nice and clean. I saw the code to accomplish this for radio buttons and I got that working fine. I tried to adapt it to checkboxes but the problem was that you can only select one radio button but multiple checkboxes.

To give you a semi-function example. If you head to the beta site, it's live (not a good practice I know) and try to customize a pen you can see what I'm trying to do. [Pensfast.com Beta](http://beta.pensfast.com)

Comment: could you add some relevant html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your updated details, this is what you want:

```
$("li.imprint").click(function(){
    var $checkbox = $(this).toggleClass('selected').find(':checkbox');
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $checkbox.attr('checked','checked');
    } else {
      $checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
    }
})
```

I am concerned that your classes are incorrect. You reference `li.imprint` in your question, but the page I visiting on your site had the class of `li.Barellimprint` Obviously, this answer won't work if the selectors are wrong. Try changing the first line to :

```
$("li.Barrelimprint").click(function(){
```

And this code would work on [this page](http://beta.pensfast.com/order-form/?pid=983).

Comment: I simplified the selector, it's actually building the form through php loops because each pen is different. Some have multiple color options, some have multiple imprinting locations, then colors per location. It's a pain in the neck really.

Comment: @Jitpal ... Ah, makes sense. Glad its working for you. The site looks really nice by the way!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me 
- it also accommodates multiple check boxes that could each an have a different initial state.

**CSS:**

```
.dragable { margin: 4px; border: 1px solid #c6e1ff; line-height: 15px;}
.dragable.selected, .dragable.unselected.selected  {background: #ebf5ff;}
.dragable.unselected {background: #ffffff;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="dragable selected ui-state-default">
    <input name="list" type="checkbox"  checked="checked" />Results</li>
    <li class="dragable unselected ui-state-default">
    <input name="list" type="checkbox" />Benefits </li>
</ul>
```

**The Javascript:**

```
<script>
    $("li.dragable").click(function(){
    var $checkbox = $(this).toggleClass('selected').find(':checkbox');
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $checkbox.attr('checked','checked');
    } else  {
      $checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
    }
})
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$("li.imprint").click(function() {
  $(this,"li.imprint").toggleClass('selected')
        .children("input:checkbox:first").attr('checked',true);
});
```

may I ask why you want to call 'click' on the checkbox?

if you want to check or uncheck checkboxes, read [this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/check-uncheck-checkbox-jquery/).

**update**

try this:

```
$("li.imprint").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected')
      $(':checkbox',this).attr('checked',$(this).is('selected'));
 });
```

Comment: That did not work. The toggleClass portion worked but the checkbox did not check.

Comment: I didn't notice your question earlier. I'm building a form where the user can select various colors. So I'm using CSS to hide the checkbox and showing an image. If the user selects the list item, the checkbox gets selected and I can get the formdata.

Comment: I tried that and it worked! However, when the user tries to deselect, the class toggles off but the checkbox remains checked.

Comment: nope ... `removeAttr('checked')` would be correct. also ... `attr('checked', 'checked)` would be correct!

Comment: I'm a little confused. How can I have it so the user toggles the checkbox status by clicking? If I set it to true or if I set it to false then only one can happen. What would be the way around that?

Comment: can you please add more details in your question... just edit your question above... I'm a little confused also on what you wanted. ;)

Comment: this is neither xhtml-valid nor does `this` represent the checkbox